# Using AWK to check column in file1 against file2

Tags: awk

Im having some difficulties with AWK in comparing the contents of one file with another.

**File1.txt**

```
142317216-|--|-tree-|-apple-|-|--
150232802-|--|-plant-|-sugar-|-granular|--
153947334-|--|-flower-|-daisy-|-single|--
153188646-|--|-soil-|-earth-|-|--
```

**File2.txt**

```
apple,99817
sugar,75844
daisy,34566
earth,75544
```

Using  **"-"** as the separator I can pull the information from **column 7.**

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="-";}  {print $7;}' file1.txt
```

**Output**

```
apple
sugar
daisy
earth
```

My full command to check if column7 within file1,txt exists in file2.txt.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="-";} NR==FR{a[$1]=$7;next} {FS=",";} $1 in a ' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Get column7, then change separator to "," and check $1 against variable a.

This shows no results and I'm struggling to get my head around the syntax to understand why. Could any perhaps give me some pointers.

Comment: You want double equals signs (comparison, not assignment) in `NR==FNR`. Nominating to close as simple typo.

Comment: @tripleee it's more than a typo, the setting of FS mid-script is wrong and won't take effect until after the first line of the 2nd file is read, and the order of files is wrong. This question has clear requirements, sample input, and an attempt shown so IMHO it should not be closed, all it needs added is the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show the output you expect and you didn't include non-matching (or duplicate) values in your files so it's a guess but this MAY be what you want:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{file2[$1];next} {print ($7 in file2 ? "present:" : "absent:"), $7}' FS=',' file2 FS='-' file1
present: apple
present: sugar
present: daisy
present: earth
```

This situation is one reason why it's possible to set variables in the file list - to change their value between files.

Since you're just starting to learn awk - get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen an answer on SO that actually used "setting variables in the file list" properly. Thank you for that. :)

Comment: Yeah it is an oft-abused functionality :-). The only real reasons to do it are a) to change values between files (not necessary with gawk BEGINFILE) and b) to ensure backslashes are not interpreted (so `\t` stays `\t` and doesn't become a literal tab character).